# Why is a JSP converted to Servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

When a JSP runs for the first time, it’s converted to a servlet. What is the reason for the conversion?

Comment: When a jsp file sends an HTTP request to server, after some processes it is converted to a servlet/ A java file. Why is it a servlet? When html doesn't do that.

Comment: I know how it is converted. The problem is why it is converted. I was asked this question at an interview and i explained how jsp engine converts it to a servlet. But it wasn't  what was asked and interviewer kept asking me why, why is it converted to a 'servlet'?. I even don't know what was expected from that question.  I was expecting anyone has any idea about it

Comment: @AxelH A JSP ***is*** converted to a Servlet. From the JSP Specification: 'The JSP page is translated to create a servlet class.' Don't post misinformation here, and check your facts before posting.

Comment: Then the interviewer is an idiot. The question should be addressed to the designers. Not to an interviewee.

Answer (score 2):

JSPs are  compiled into Java servlets on the server-side. Their main purpose is to make it easier to write and maintain HTML/CSS/JS since doing that in an actual servlet includes a lot of work.

Basically, the idea is `that web designers can create the UI` of the web page and then Java programmers can add the dynamic content. Web designers do not have to know Java to work with JSP and don't have to be aware of creating classes and inheritance or whatever like they would when writing servlets. Get familiar with MVC architecture and everything will make sense.

[image]

Comment: @AxelH A JSP ***is*** converted to a Servlet. From the JSP Specification: 'The JSP page is translated to create a servlet class.' Don't post misinformation here, and check your facts before posting.

Comment: @AxelH You made the misstatement three times, at least. Three comments is not excessive in that circumstance. 'JSP Specification' is not hard to find. I'm astonished you are answering questions about it when you haven't even read it and don't appear to know the first thing about it.

Comment: @EJP can you answer my question then? Still the question doesn't  change

Comment: @user2431205 I don't know what sort of an answer you're expecting here. The only one I can give you is 'because that's the way they designed it'.